# Choosing combinations from Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dataset, data-science

A Dataframe contains stock data (the data in the dataframe is irrelevant and omitted):

```
      open   high   low   close
MSFT
APPL
IBM
GM
XP
INTC
```

The problem: select combinations of 3 stocks such that

1. order is not important: if MSFT/APPL/IBM has been calculated then IBM/MSFT/APPL is redundant
2. a combination cannot have duplicates: cannot have MSFT/MSFT/APPL

For example, if only selecting two stocks at a time then select the combinations with an "X" below. This can be extended to 3 dimensions.

```
        MSFT   APPL   IBM   GM   XP   INTC
MSFT
APPL    X
IBM     X      X     
GM      X      X     X
XP      X      X     X      X 
INTC    X      X     X      X    X
```

I can do this in a non-pythonic way (3 nested loops) but I'm looking for a better solution.

A solution that doesn't hold the entire cube in memory is necessary. The dataset is large and only cumulative results are kept, not the combinations or their results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.combination`. It's quite useful, fast, and it attends both of your requirements.

```
from itertools import combinations

stocks = ['MSFT','APPL','IBM','GM','XP','INTC']
list(combinations(iterable=stocks, r=2))
```

then modify the `r` parameter as intended (length of combinations).

Comment: I did something like this since because of combinatorial explosion memory requirements with large data sets. Thanks for your answer!


`code

stocks = ['MSFT','APPL','IBM','GM','XP','INTC']
combos=combinations(iterable=stocks, r=3)
for combo in combos:
    #do something

code`